# Use of Unresolved Identifier firebase function

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've defined the function sendDataToDatabase but for some reason it's not resolving photoUrl?

I've been trying to figure out what might be causing this for 6 hours now and can't seem to find a solution, if anyone could provide some help it would be appreciated.

```
    @IBAction func shareButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    ProgressHUD.show("Waiting...", interaction: false)
    if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
        let photoId = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "manifest-bit-233115.appspot.com").child("posts").child(photoId)
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, Error) in
           if Error != nil {
                return
           }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (URL, Error) -> Void in
                if (Error != nil) {
                    //handle any errors
                } else {
                    //get download url
                    let photoUrl = URL?.absoluteString
                }
                self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl!)
        })
    }
)}

 func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl!) {
     let ref = Database.database().reference()
     //let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
     let postsRef = ref.child("posts")
     let newPostId = postsRef.childByAutoId().key
     let newPostRef = postsRef.child(newPostId!)

     newPostRef.setValue(["photoUrl": photoUrl])

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues.

You have to call `sendDataToDatabase` only in the `else` branch and declare the parameters with starting lowercase letters.
The parameters are **not** types.

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) -> Void in
   if let error = error {
      //handle any errors
   } else {
     //get download url
     let photoUrl = url!.absoluteString
     self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl)
   }
})
```

and you have to declare the type in the function

```
func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String) { ...
```

Comment: My goal is to place the download url for photos/videos in the database once they have finished uploading to firebase, this was the only solution I could find to it, do you know of a more efficient way? as the preferred method metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That's another question and I'm not not familiar with FireBase

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (URL, Error) -> Void in
    if (Error != nil) {
        //handle any errors
    } else {
        //get download url
        let photoUrl = URL?.absoluteString
    }
    self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl!)
})
```

photoUrl will only be available within the else clause, since that's where it's defined, and you can not use it outside of that scope.

Also, this:

```
func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl!)
```

should probably be:

```
func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String)
```

It's also a good idea to not name variables `URL` and `Error`, since they are identical to the URL and Error classes. Name them `url` and `error` instead.